# Kivy Recorder not clicking correct location

Tags: python, kivy, recorder

I am having trouble figuring out why the kivy recorder is clicking in a spot not where it says it will. In my app, I print the touch variable in my on_touch_down event and it says:

RecorderMotionEvent spos=(0.645703125, 0.0) pos=(1239.75, 0.0)

Instead of clicking at 1239.75,0 it clicks about the middle top right of my window. Also, regardless of what pos I tell it to click (it could be 0,0), it always clicks the same spot of the window.
My window is 1920,1080. My recorder file looks like this (without the empty lines inbetween):

#RECORDER1.0

(0.0015017986297607422, 'keydown', 0, {'key': 289, 'scancode': None, 'is_touch': False, 'modifier': None, 'codepoint': None})

(0.0015017986297607422, 'keyboard', 0, {'key': 289, 'scancode': None, 'is_touch': False, 'modifier': None, 'codepoint': None})

(0.03768434524536133, 'keyup', 0, {'key': 289, 'scancode': None, 'is_touch': False, 'modifier': None, 'codepoint': None})

(0.1087048053741455, 'begin', 1, {'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': 0.645703125, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': 0.0})

(0.1346497535705566, 'update', 1, {'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': 0.645703125, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': 0.0})

(0.1994667053222656, 'end', 1, {'profile': ['pos'], 'sx': 0.645703125, 'is_touch': True, 'sy': 0.0})

Has anyone else run into this problem? I have tried to debug it but haven't been able to figure this out. I'm using kivy 1.10 and python 3.5.

EDIT:The recorder uses a scale of 0-1 for window pos so I've edited that but it still clicks the same spot of the window, the middle top right lol

Comment: Do you have any postproc:calibration section in your kivy config maybe?

Comment: I don't belive so, no. My config settings for kivy are just: Config.set('input', 'mouse', 'mouse,multitouch_on_demand')
Config.set('kivy', 'exit_on_escape', '0') I also ensured that it was using the correct Window, which would be silly if it wasn't, just good to check I guess.

Comment: Maybie it's not the part of the screen where it's clicking that is the problem because the spot where it clicks is where another widget is. So it ends up running the event for the widget at that screen location. Seems pretty odd though why it would do that.